# np.loadtxt() cannot convert str to float error

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am attempting to work with the `np.loadtxt()` method. (Note: please do not recommend using something else as I am required to use this.)

I have only 1 header, so I am skipping it via the `skiprows=1` argument. The next row (and every subsequent row) in the CSV file looks like this:

```
1900,3.00E+04,4.00E+03,4.83E+04
```

When I run this code:

```
file_name = 'data.csv'
data = np.loadtxt(file_name, skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
```

I get this:

> `ValueError: couldn't convert str to float '1900, 3.00E+04, 4.00E+03, 4.83E+04'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Running your code as-is works fine?

Comment: "The next row (and every subsequent row) in the csv file looks like this:" Are you sure? The error says it sees extra spaces in the input.

Comment: As posted, this issue is not reproducible.  What version of numpy are you using?  `print(np.__version__)`  What version of python?

Comment: Could you provide the first couple of lines of the input file? At which position is the string `1900,3.00E+04,4.00E+03,4.83E+04` approximately located? Also which version of NumPy and Python are you using?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Yes, I am sure that every row looks like that. The next row is "1901,4.72E+04,6.10E+03,4.82E+04". The row after that is "1902,7.02E+04,9.80E+03,4.15E+04".  That's why I cannot figure out why there are spaces included in the error message. Python version is 3.7.3. NumPy version is 1.16.4

Comment: Works for me too. Maybe post a link to the file?

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I actually had to restart the IDE (I was using Spyder), and now it's running perfectly fine. Hopefully somebody else running into this same issue reaches a solution as simple as mine.

Comment: @MoKaiser I've used both [`Pycharm`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=windows&code=PCC) and `Spyder` and [`Pycharm`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=windows&code=PCC) is alot less buggy. I recommend it.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Thank you! :) Looks like I'll be making the move to Pycharm.